# Nested while loops with scatter update in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

variable `v1=[[0,0],[0,0]]` 
Tensor `t1=[[-1,0],[1,1]]`

I want output `op=[[1,0],[0,2]]`

**Logic:**
If `t1==-1` then ignore. Else use `t1` value as index for `v1` and add 1 to that `v1` value.

**Python equivalent :**

```
for row in range(len(t1)):
    for col in range(len(t1[row])):
        t1_val=t1[row][col];
        if t1_val!=-1:
            v1[row][t1_val]+=1
```

I looked through lot of questions on while loops and scatter update but couldn't figure out how to solve the above problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may try `tf.map_fn`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

v1 = tf.Variable([[0,0],[0,0]], dtype=tf.int32)
t1 = tf.constant([[-1,0],[1,1]], dtype=tf.int32)

result = tf.map_fn(lambda x: x[0]+tf.math.bincount(tf.gather_nd(x[1], tf.where(tf.not_equal(x[1],-1))),minlength=x[0].shape[0])
                   , [v1,t1]
                   , dtype=tf.int32)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(result))

# print
[[1 0]
 [0 2]]
```